# Bootstrap input text with addon not align

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm a little bit confuse on how i will make a input text align on my tabs see the picture below for better visualization.
http://i59.tinypic.com/2nrlyd1.png
here is the code:

HTML

```
<div class="row">
                            <div class="tabbable tabs-left">
                               <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                   <li><a href="#a" data-toggle="tab">Public</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="#c" data-toggle="tab">Private</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="#c" data-toggle="tab">Pending</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="#c" data-toggle="tab">Rejected</a></li>
                                   <li>
                                   <li>
                                      <div class="input-group merged">
                                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left fa-fw"></i></span>
                                      </div>
                                 </li>
                               </ul>
                            <div class="tab-content">
                             <div class="tab-pane active" id="a">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, charetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. 
                                 Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero.</div>
                             <div class="tab-pane" id="b">Secondo sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan. 
                                 Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.</div>
                             <div class="tab-pane" id="c">Thirdamuno, ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. 
                                 Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae. </div>
                            </div>
                           </div> <!-- /tabs -->
                        </div><!--row -->
```

here is the CSS provided for input text with addon

```
.input-group-addon {background-color: #fff;}
.merged input:first-child{border-right: 0px;}
.merged .input-group-addon + input{border-left: 0px;}
```

Comment: Your picture shows one input field, and nothing is "misaligned". Please be more specific, or show a better picture. In any case, you could always just try "display: inline-block".

Comment: sorry for the unspecific question. my question is how the input text be small to fit in the line beside of the 5 tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, put the input text into another div or something similar and then  set a max size to that div, and then put the input text into it as a child and it should not exceed the with of that so long as you have like max-width: 100%, max-height: 100%, and so forth.

Example:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">
      <input //code goes here>
   </div>
</div>

.parent {
   width: 100px;
   height: 50px;
}

.child {
   max-width: 100%;
   max-height: 100%;
}

input {
   display: block; 
   margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: My pleasure. Feel free to ask any more questions if the above doesn't work or you need it to do something else (didn't actually test it, but seems about right).